# MyMobiler unnable to connect to device (via WiFi)

Tags: remote-control

I have a task for my company to remotely control Android devices in the whole company from PC. So I need an app which could control Android Device from PC (not vice versa). I found an app called MyMobiler (http://mymobiler.com/index.html). This app allows me to view/control Android device from PC. You just need to download an app from Google Play and standalone program for PC. 
Everything works fine with USB (I can control and view the device from PC), but when I try to connect it via Wifi, I am unable to do it. Basically I get an IP address on my Android device, and I write this IP address in the "Connect IP" window (http://mymobiler.com/android-wifi-keyboard.html). But when I press "Connect", I wait for about 30 seconds and get an error which say "Unnable to connect your device ..... [my IP address]". Any ideas? Thank you for any responses and appreciate any help :)

**EDIT**: This is how I get IP address of the network on my Android phone: 
I downloaded MyMobiler app from Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mymobiler.android). When I first launch it, I have to turn big blue button ON (http://mymobiler.com/android-setup-start.html) and when on my PC, I have to press "Connect" button to connect with USB. When in my Android app the screen changes from localhost to IP address. This is how I get IP address. When back to PC I press "Connect IP" and typ this exact IP (for ex.: 192.168.2.132). When I press "Connect" and after 30 seconds waiting, I get "Unnable to connect device ...[my IP]"

Comment: Are the devices in the same WiFi network, or on mobile data? Some carriers use NAT and/or firewalling on their data plans, which prevents these kinds of direct connections.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to describe how you're finding the IP address of the Android device. If that's wrong, then connecting will fail in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: onik, I pretty sure I am on the same network (I connected my Android device to the TEST WiFi network, and on PC I have connected to the same TEST network). I will ask my manager about NAT, but I have tested this stuff in home - same thing. Dan Hulme, one second :)

Comment: Do you see the `mobiler service : yes` and `root : yes` texts on the screen?

Comment: When I am trying to connect via WiFi it constantly changes from  Yes to No (just like with USB). I also tried to ping that IP adress (192.168.2.132), it says "Reply from 192.168.2.133: Destination host unreachable. ".

Answer (score 1):

OK, I changed to another network and it started to working. It may be some permission which denied my app from working. Thank you very much, onik, for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://www.teamviewer.com. For personal use it's free.

Comment: Does it let you control the phone from the PC, or only vice-versa? The website doesn't advertise that as a feature.

Comment: I suppose you can do it either way